# Remove entire list elements which contain a certain string

Tags: r, list

var1 is a list:

```
var1 <- list(c("tall tree", "fruits", "star"),  
             c("tree tall", "pine tree", "tree pine", "black forest", "water"), 
             c("apple", "orange", "grapes"), 
             c("ancient pine tree", "all trees"))
```

I need to remove those elements entirely from the list which contains the term "pine".

The desired answer is a list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "tall tree" "fruits"    "star"    
[[2]]
[1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var1[lapply(var1,function(x) length(grep("pine",x,value=FALSE))) == 0]
```

Answer (score 17):

You could try `Filter` here

```
Filter(function(x) !any(grepl("pine", x)), var1)
# [[1]]
# [1] "tall tree" "fruits"    "star"     
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add another option. The "str_" functions in the stringr package are great for pattern matching in lists.

If you were looking for all list entries that *match* you could use:

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(var1,pattern="pine")
```

but since you want list entries that *don't* match, you can use:

```
library(stringr)
var1[!str_detect(var1,pattern="pine")]
```

`str_detect(list,pattern)` returns a list of logicals, so you can use the inverse (!) to subset your list to entries that do not match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one can perform:

```
 var2<-lapply(var1,function(x) if(all(grepl(pattern = "^(?!.*pine).*$",x,perl = T)==T)) return(x) else NA);var2[!is.na(var2)]
```